# Twitter Feed Icon color change

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap, widget, feed

Hi I am using this feed code where I am using white background. I want to change the twitter bird icon to blue. Anyone have any suggestion?

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>

<script>

new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 3000,
  width: 'auto',
  height: 150,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#FFFFFF',
      color: '#979797'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#626262',
      links: '#00B79F'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().setUser('Soumya123').start();
</script>
```

Here is the image showed the Icon need to be change
[image]